# How to add SUBSYSTEM==”usb”, ATTR{idVendor}==”04E8″, MODE=”0666″, GROUP=”plugdev” to my 51-android.rules on Linux?

Tags: android-studio, samsung-mobile, attr, vendor, mtp

I am trying to link my Samsung device to my android studio. I am using Ubuntu so following directions online I created my */etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules* file but when I am trying to direct inside it and touch the **SUBSYSTEM==”usb”, ATTR{idVendor}==”04E8″, MODE=”0666″, GROUP=”plugdev”** it says that it is not a directory.

How could I add it to my 51-android.rules?

Answer (score 0):

- run the command

`sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`

- then a text editor will open and add the line you want. In this case

`SUBSYSTEM==”usb”, ATTR{idVendor}==”04E8″, MODE=”0666″, GROUP=”plugdev”`

- The idVendor is specific to the manufacturer. See [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/599086/unable-to-use-my-android-device-as-android-emulator-using-android-studio) for more details.